# $a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ if $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is it if we use 1 2 3 4 mod 5 and we take x^3 of these numbers, we come to: 1 3 2 4 (all numbers are different as you can see)? Why are they all different. Thanks

Explanation:
$a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ if $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime. You know that $\phi(5) = 5 - 1 = 4$, so if the exponent - say $k$ - is relatively prime to $4$, then the values of $x^k$ for $x \in {1, 2, 3, 4}$ will be all different.
How can we conclude from $a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$
that all numbers are different?

Comment: If $a^k = a^m$ for some $k, m$, $a^{k-m} = 1 \pmod{p}$.  This means $k - m \equiv 0 \mod p$, so $k = m \pmod p$.

Comment: @gravitybeatle Thank you! But I only have one exponent k here, which is 3. What does m represent in my exemple?

Comment: $p-1$ for the last two. when p is prime.

Comment: Now I am really lost. Can someone please explain me why 1 3 2 4 are all different. They say that it can be explained with the Euler's theorem, but I can't manage to do that.

Comment: multiply both sides of the congruence by a ...

Comment: Which congruence are you talking about?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee 1 3 2 4 are all not congruent to each other

Comment: I know but $a^{\varphi(p)+n}\equiv a^n\pmod p$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee But what can we conclude from there?

Comment: that if it holds for all $n$ less than $\varphi(p)$ it'll work for all $n$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I want to proof that if we use 1 2 3 4 mod 5 and we take x^3 of these numbers, we come to all different numbers. You are only giving short, very unclear answers. Please take some time and give one, full answer. Thanks

Comment: How can a^ϕ(p)≡1 help us with the proof?

Answer (score 1):

We have by Euler's theorem that $a^{\phi(p)}\equiv1\pmod p$ if $(a,p)=1$,

so, if $bc\equiv1\bmod\phi(p)$, then $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}\equiv a^1=a\pmod p$,

so the map $a\mapsto a^b$ is invertible ($a\mapsto a^c)$ and therefore bijective.

For your particular example, take $p=5$, $\phi(p)=4$, $b=3$, and $c=3$.

Then the map $a\mapsto a^3$, which takes $1\mapsto1, 2\mapsto3, 3\mapsto2, $ and $4\mapsto4$ is its own inverse:

$$1\mapsto1\mapsto1, 2\mapsto3\mapsto2, 3\mapsto2\mapsto3, \text{ and } 4\mapsto4\mapsto4.$$

If the map were not one-to-one, it could not be inverted.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand anything :)

Comment: Are there not any easier explanations?

Comment: I produced an inverse for the map $a\mapsto a^3\pmod 5$, so therefore that map is one-to-one

Comment: Can we only work with numbers? Can you explain why each number is different in my particular case?

Comment: I added more numbers to my answer; it might be instructive for you to consider $a\mapsto a^2,$ which is not invertible modulo $5$

Comment: Thank you, but this is to difficult for me. I need to proof it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation with  *Lagrange's theorem*:

You have to show the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is *injective* in the multiplicative group $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times$. As  it is a group homomorphism because the group is commutative, it amounts to showing its kernel is $\{1\}$.

Consider $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $x^3=1$. This implies the order of $x$ is a divisor of $3$. But as it is an element of the  group $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times$, of order $4$, it is also, by *Lagrange*, a divisor of $4$, and $\gcd(3,4)=1$. Therefore, necessarily, we have $x=1$.

*Some details*:

Denote, for any $x\in(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times$, $o(x)$ (the *order* of $x$) the least positive integer $k$ such that $x^k\equiv 1\mod 5$. It is easy to show that if $x^\ell\equiv 1\mod 5$, then $\ell$ is a multiple of $o(x)$.

Now suppose $x^3\equiv y^3\mod 5$. If we denote $y^{-1}$  the inverse of $y\bmod 5$, this implies that $x^3(y^3)^{-1}=\bigl(xy^{-1}\bigr)^3\equiv 1\mod 5$. By the property mentioned in the above §, $3$ is a multiple of $o(xy^{-1})$. Since $3$ is prime, this order is therefore  either $1$ or $3$.

However, one can show that this order is also a divisor or $\#(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times$, which is $4$. As $3\not\mid 4$, the only solution is $\;o(xy^{-1})=1$, which means, by definition, that $xy^{-1}=1$, whence, multiplying both sides by $y$, $x=y$.

Comment: Do you at least know what is the order of an element in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Comment: What do you know about this last set?

Comment: I know nothing about number theory. Can we not proof it by saying that there are two different x that map to the same residue and then proof a contradiction?

Comment: That's more or less what I had in mind when I mentioned the kernel and the order of the element. I'll try to post a sketch of the details, which you should check by yourself –  and ask questions if necessary.

Comment: thank you very much. Will you do it now?

Comment: 'Tis done${ }$.

Comment: I understood everything, but not "It is easy to show that if xℓ≡1mod5, then ℓ is a multiple of o(x)." Can you explain why it is the case?

Comment: It is linked to euclidean division in $\mathbf Z$: divide $\ell$ by $o(x)$: you have a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$ satisfying the relation $\ell=q\cdot o(x)+r,\quad 0\le r<o(x)$, so $x^\ell=\bigl(x^{o(x)}\bigr)^q\,x^r$, i.e. $\;1=1^q\, x^r$. However, if $r>0$,   $x^r=1$ contradicts the minimality of $o(x)$. Therefore $r=0$, which means that $o(x)$ divides $\ell$. This is exactly the way one proves that all ideals of $\mathbf Z$ are principal, if that is meaningful to you.

Comment: x^3≡y^3 mod5 <=>(xy^−1)^3≡1 mod5 3 is a multiple of o(xy−1). Since 3 is prime, this order is therefore either 1 or 3. I now just need an easier way to show that the only corect one is 1. Can't I prove it on a much easier way? Like with the Euler's theorem that a^4≡1 or just something much easier that can show that 1 is the only correct answer?

Comment: Euler's theorem (actually Fermat's theorem) tells you the order of all nonzero elements  is a divisor of $4$, so it can't be $3$. Everything relies on the notion of order of an element (which, incidentally, is a notion the group theory).

Comment: each of your comments gets more and more difficult. I am not porfessional. You say the order of all nonzero elements is a divisor of 4. Let's take 3^3 with order 3, is equal to 9 and is not a divisor of 4. Please explain it clearly I don't understand anything about the notions you use.

Comment: We have by Euler's theorem that a^ϕ(p)≡1(modp) if (a,p)=1. So in my case they are all equal to 4? because ϕ(p)=4. Why did you say DIVISORS of 4?

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing the order of an element (the least positive integer such that …) and the exponent. We indeed have $3^2\equiv 4\bmod 5$, $3^3\equiv 2\bmod 5$ and $3^4\equiv 4^2\equiv 1\bmod 5$, so the order of $3$ is $4$.

Comment: Because the order is the *least* exponent having this property. When you have an exponent with the property, you cannot say *a priori* it is the least. For instance $2$ and $3$ indeed have order $4$, but $4$ has order $2$.

Comment: Euler's theorem (actually Fermat's theorem) tells you the order of all nonzero elements is a divisor of 4. 1) I still don't understand what an order is. 2) When did he say that? He is talking about the exponent ϕ(p) and not about orders. Please don't use difficult names and notations, explain it simply.

Comment: And AGAIN: I know NOTHING about number theory.

Comment: Did you follow the computations in my last but one comment? As to the difficulty of names/notations, it is easier to understand  a notion  or a notation than  reading endlessly a circumlocution. In geometry, you don't repeat *ad nauseam*  ‘ a quadrilateral with pairwise parallel sides’, you simply say a parallelogram. Can't you make this very little effort?

Comment: I suppose you know at least what congruences are, since you use Euler and Fermat's theorems.

Comment: Yes, congruence I know.

Comment: The order of an element x in a group G is the smallest positive integer n for which x^n is the identity element. What is an 'identity element'?

Comment: The multiplicative unit – the congruence class of $1$ in the present case.

Comment: x^3≡y^3 mod5 <=>(xy^−1)^3≡1 mod 5 all I have to do now is proof that xy^-1 is equal to 1

Comment: With the notion of order, this is obvious. This being said, as there are only $4$ elements, it is not long to check  that a single element has a cube equal to one. Of course, if you prime number were $541$, it would be a bit longer… and you would see clearly why thinking  can be more fruitful than computing.

Comment: Can't I just say that x^3 ≡ y^3 (mod 29) ⟺ (xy^-1)^3  ≡ 1 (mod 29) ⟺ xy^-1=29n

Comment: and now proof that x=y?

Comment: $x^3\equiv y^3\implies( x^3)^{19}\equiv(y^3)^{19}\iff x^{57}\equiv y^{57}$.  Now $57\equiv1\mod \varphi(29)$ so $x\equiv x^{57}\equiv y^{57}\equiv y\mod 29$ (by Fermat).

Comment: But you just combined mod φ(29) with mod29... maybe mod φ(29)(=28?) it is 1, but why is it one if we go to mod 29?

Comment: Euler's theorem can be written as $a^{N}\equiv a^{N\bmod\varphi(n)}\mod n$ for any $a$ coprime to $n$ since $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few explanations:

- multiplicative inverses ( modular equivalent to reciprocal (division of 1 by a number)) are unique when defined.
- $a^n=-(-a)^n$ when $n$ is odd. as congruence is a weakened version of equality, it follows this rule as well.

The way the above congruence flows into this is if they are congrurnt to 1, decreasing the exponent by 1 is taking the multiplicative inverse.